# Readthedocs + Sphinx: Readthedocs is not reading translated files

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am using Sphinx to write the documentation and I'm currently hosting it in
readthedocs.org
.
It has successfully built the [default page](https://habi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but I'm having trouble loading https://habi.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/ from the [git](https://github.com/Habi-Thapa/readdocs/tree/master/_build/html).

Why is the page in 'ja' not loading? What changes should I make?

Comment: Seems like Readthedocs doesn't read the _build/Html/{locale} automatically. You need to create a separate project with a different language section. Then add that as a translation project from the admin menu.